# Solr > q query with boosting OR another field

Tags: solr

http://www.blabla_solr.com:8080/searcher/solrcore/select?q=+text&qf=Field1 Field2^999&defType=dismax

OR search same value in another field  &fq=Field3:*text*

So I am searhing "text" value in Field1 and Field2 fields if they don't contain it, check Field3 which is a string typed field.

What should be the best way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory

I have another field type which uses solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory logic.